# How to extract array from the first element of triples in 2d array of triples using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array with shape `(480, 640, 3)` and I want to create an array made up of all the first elements from the triples using numpy. I tried

`newArray = array[np.arange(array.shape[0]),np.arange(array.shape[1]),0]`

but that returns this:

`cannot be broadcast to a single shape`

I understand why, and if that did work it wouldn't really be what I wanted anyway. I want to end up with an array with shape `(480, 640)`, and that command would have given me a 1d array.

So, how do I get what I want? I've been browsing the docs and tutorials on numpy, but there's so much terminology I don't know (I just started using numpy today) that I can't figure out what I need to do.

Comment: Example input & output please

Comment: What sort of input/output are you looking for? I don't want to print the entire array... I did say what error it returned.

Comment: @Johonn you can illustrate input and output with a smaller array, say of shape `(5, 6, 3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to take a slice along the depth axis:

```
In [8]: a = np.ones((480,640,3))

In [9]: a[:,:,0]
Out[9]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       ..., 
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.]])

In [10]: a[:,:,0].shape
Out[10]: (480, 640)
```